# Run checks against user-generated Python code

Tags: python, security

I am trying to make a website where users can program in Python, or Octave. Much like on the e-learning website [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/). The user enters his code on the website and this is then sent to a webserver which processes the code and returns the response to the user. I got it working, but I think it's highly unsafe since I do not run any checks against the code. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427361/how-does-udacity-web-python-interpreter-work) that Udacity ships the code off to a sandboxed cluster and runs their own tests against it to see if it passes.

So my question is this: what can happen if I don't run checks against this code? Could my whole website be deleted by a clever, malicious user? And what should I test this code for to make sure "nothing bad happens"?

Comment: It's literally impossible to test for this (except for executing the code and seeing what happens). You want to sandbox the code to make sure an user can only do what you want him to do.

Comment: Here's a safe alternative: http://www.skulpt.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would depend upon a few things:

- Are you running it as a restricted user?
- Do you have a maximum allowable run time?
- Do you allow network access or restrict it at all?

Malicious code as a root user could delete your server contents. Malicious non-root code code find a way to elevate and still do harm.
Non root code could forkbomb or find other ways to consume all available server resources.
Unrestricted code could initiate denial of service attacks on web-resources. It could spider your internal network and post the details across to a malicious individual to give further information to make more coordinated attacks.

With file and subprocess access - it could write out x86 or C code, assemble/compile/link and run it.

---

As for securing it - have this code run as the least privileged user on a system, or better still inside a dedicated VM/container.

You could find a way to run it within a restricted python with a very limited set of core libraries and builtins available - disabling networking, subprocessing, file opening, threading.

For any suggested methods - you will need to investigate the implications and the weaknesses of them.

One final alternative is to investigate "pyjamas" - which does python in a browser with conversion to JS, and if it could be made to run entirely in the browser. That then means that the users code, and potentially result validation, runs in their browser - and not your server.